# In Userform Link Checkboxes with options button

Tags: vba, checkbox

I have created a userform (to change the column and row width of active sheet or all sheets )which has three frames. In the first frame I have given two option box. Firsts option box : - To change the row and column width from Column B onwards and other option box to change the row column width from column c onwards. User will select anyone of them and then move to second frame: which has again two options one to make the changes in active sheet and second option box to make the changes in all the sheets. So if the user in the first form will select first option (change row and column width from B onwards and in the second frame will select active sheet then the column and row width will change from Column B onwards in the active sheet and so on...

Now I want to create third fram which has 3 checkboxes which has name of 3 sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3.) I want that when the user has selected his options in frame one and two if the user in the third fram select any of the checkboxes or all of the checkboxes then the changes should not apply in the sheetname mentioned in any of the 3 checkboxes which he has selected.

I have successfully executed frame one and frame 2 however struggling to create a code for frame 3 which will have 3 checkboxes (which contains name of 3 sheets) which is to excluded to make any row and column width changes.

Please find below my codes which are in the module

```
Sub rowcolactivesheetb()
    Dim exworkb As Workbook
    Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow1 As Long
    Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
    Dim firstrowDB As Long
        With ActiveSheet
            lastrow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lastcolumn1 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
            Selection.Cells.RowHeight = 9.14
            Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = 7.14
        End With
End Sub

Sub rowcolallsheetb()
    Dim exworkb As Workbook
    Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow1 As Long
    Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
    Dim firstrowDB As Long
    Dim Z As Integer
    Dim ShtNames() As String

    ReDim ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    For Z = 1 To Sheets.Count
        ShtNames(Z) = Sheets(Z).Name
        Sheets(Z).Select
        lastrow1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Z).Range(Sheets(Z).Cells(1, 2), Sheets(Z).Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
        Selection.Cells.RowHeight = 9.14
        Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = 7.14
    Next Z
End Sub

Sub rowcolactivesheetc()
    Dim exworkb As Workbook
    Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow1 As Long
    Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
    Dim firstrowDB As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn1 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
        Selection.Cells.RowHeight = 9.14
        Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = 7.14
    End With
End Sub

Sub rowcolallsheetc()

    Dim exworkb As Workbook
    Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow1 As Long
    Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
    Dim firstrowDB As Long
    Dim Z As Integer
    Dim ShtNames() As String

    ReDim ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    For Z = 1 To Sheets.Count

        ShtNames(Z) = Sheets(Z).Name

        Sheets(Z).Select

        lastrow1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        lastcolumn1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Z).Range(Sheets(Z).Cells(1, 3), Sheets(Z).Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select

        Selection.Cells.RowHeight = 9.14

        Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = 7.14

    Next Z

End Sub
```

Userform code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If Me.OptionButton5.Value = True Then

        If Me.OptionButton7.Value = True Then

            Call rowcolactivesheetb

        ElseIf Me.OptionButton8.Value = True Then

            rowcolallsheetb

        End If

    End If

    If Me.OptionButton6.Value = True Then

        If Me.OptionButton7.Value = True Then

            Call rowcolactivesheetc

        ElseIf Me.OptionButton8.Value = True Then

            rowcolallsheetc

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the difference between this question and [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43434210/6535336)?

Comment: My first sheet name is Cover so in the user form code I have added this code but now I am wondering how to loop other checkboxes.

Comment: If Me.OptionButton6.Value = True Then
If Me.OptionButton8.Value = True Then
If Me.CheckBox1.Value = Me.CheckBox2.Value = Me.CheckBox3.Value = Me.CheckBox4.Value = False Then
Call rowcolallsheetc
ElseIf Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
rowcolallsheetccover
End If
End If
End If

Comment: That looks to be the same code as the previous question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vba userform , if any of the checkboxes in the frame is true then macro should not be applied on the sheetname mentioned in the checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434210/vba-userform-if-any-of-the-checkboxes-in-the-frame-is-true-then-macro-should-n)

Comment: yes that is what exactly I want that if any of the checkboxes in the frame is true then macro should not apply in the sheetname mentioned in check box can you please suggest a code for this as I am really struggling with this one

Comment: But why have you asked two questions?  What is the difference between the two?  As I said, the code appears identical and, as far as I can tell, the wording of the question is identical.  So why waste everyone's time by asking twice?

Comment: because I wasnt able to modify my previous code so I posted a new thread

Comment: I have just confirmed that apart from whitespace, the code in the two questions is identical.  So why create a new thread to post the same code?